People knock down a wall and find a pot full of an evil dormant creature
When I was a child, I saw a film on TV that scared me to death. All I can remember is some people knocked down a wall in a house and inside the wall they found one or more pots, and inside these pots were some kind of dormant creature that was evil. Anybody have any idea what film this is? It was on TV in possibly late 70'- early 80's.

Not what you are looking for, but Prometheus (2012) has a similar scene where a team enters a room on another planet that has pots with black goo spawning evil creatures of some kind. (Has been a while since I saw it.)

A very old question, but I saw it under 'active' (not sure why) and I think I have a fit: the episode 'Baby' of the 1976 ITV horror series Beasts. A recap with the similarities highlighted: After a man and his pregnant wife move to a house in the country, the renovators knock down a wall and discover a clay pot in it with a mummified creature inside. Soon after, the wife is terrorized by evil forces. Here's a clip.

The timing seems off, but is it possibly John Carpenter's Prince of Darkness?  It aired in 1987. 

A sinister secret has been kept in the basement of an abandoned Los Angeles church for many years. With the death of a priest belonging to a mysterious sect, another priest opens the door to the basement and discovers a vat containing a green liquid. The priest contacts a group of physics graduate students to investigate it. Unfortunately, they discover that the liquid contains the essence of Satan himself, and they also discover that he will release HIS father - an all-powerful Anti-God! The liquid later comes to life itself, turning some of the students into zombies as the Devil comes forward to release his father. Will these students be able to stop him?


Alien Resurection matches the creatures in jars. The timeline or house doesn't fit but theres a scene when some of the characters enter a lab and see several creatures in jars. One of them was a clone of Ripley that was pleading to be killed.
